# java разница в String из бд и из исходного кода

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Пытаюсь отправлять смайлы в телеграм бот. коды смайлов в бд, но вместо смайлов в сообщении приходит текст кода этого смайла а не сам эмоджи. однако, если ввести тот же код смайла в исходный код программы через `String = "\ud83c\udf4f";`
то все окей. Кроме того, сравнение одинакового кода в бд и тексте программы тоже не выполняется, то еть:

```
if(prodtype[2].equals("\ud83c\udf4f")) {
        emm = "\ud83c\udf4f";
    }
```

код выше не выполяется, хотя в бд и программе одинаковые полностью символы. В чем загвоздка?

Comment: Проблема в непонимании экранирования символов в исходном коде. В исходном  коде после разбора его компилятором остаётся два символа, а а базе у вас видимо лежит 12

Comment: @Alexey Ten пробовал добавлять и в базу и в исходный код доп слэш для экранирования, эффекта не дало

Comment: Выведите значение `prodtype[2]` в консоль хотя бы, станет понятнее что там из БД приходит и в каком виде.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В базе нужно хранить не `\ud83c\udf4f`, а .

То что в коде записано как `String s = "\ud83c\udf4f"` преобразуется компилятором в `String s = ""`;

PS: преобразовать можно прямо в
IntelliJ IDEA поставив курсор на строку, нажав Alt+Enter и выбрав в меню *Replace unicode...* или онлайн [конвертером](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html)

Comment: Да круто. Юникод подложил еще одни грабли: что ascii - это еще не все символы, и надо понимать, как происходит преобразование

Comment: Спасибо, вы полностью правы. Пользуюсь eclipse поэтому конвертер сделал свое дело!